# Compute the given limit

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^{+}} x^{0.7}(\ln(e^{x}  - 1))$$

Since $\ln(0)$ is undefined, I know I need to simplify that expression, as of now what I did was take $\ln(e^{x}(1- e^{-x})$. ie Take $e^{x}$ out and then use the property $\ln(ab) = \ln a + \ln b$ which still leaves me with $\ln(1 - e^{-x})$. Is there any way to simplify this expression?

Comment: Please format with MathJax ! Thanks.

Comment: I think a downvote ought to be used for the quality of the question and not the format, nevertheless.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla That's not true. As x approaches 0, that limit approaches negative infinity.

Comment: My bad, right. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

Numbers like decimals in calculus are so rare (except for using calculus for approximations) that I have to replace the exponent $0.7$ by $n$. Now we can put $e^{x} - 1=t$ so that $t\to 0^{+}$ as $x\to 0^{+}$ and then $$\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}x^{n}\log(e^{x}-1)=\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}(\log(1+t))^{n}\log t=\lim_{t\to 0^{+}}\left(\frac{\log(1+t)}{t}\right)^{n} \cdot t^{n} \log t$$ and this evaluates to $0$ because first factor tends to $1$ and second factor tends to $0$ (because $n>0$).

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^{+}} x^{0.7}(\ln(e^{x}  - 1))$$
Invert the sign of the exponent and move it to the denominator:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^{+}} \frac {\ln(e^{x}  - 1)} {x^{-0.7}}$$
Apply [L'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule):
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^{+}} \frac {{e^{x}}/(e^{x}-1)} {-0.7x^{-1.7}}$$
Rearrange terms and expand:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^{+}} \frac {{e^{x}x^{1.7}}} {0.7-0.7e^{x}}$$
Apply L'Hôpital's rule again:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^{+}} \frac {{e^{x}(x^{1.7}+1.7x^{0.7})}} {-0.7e^{x}}$$
Cancel the $e^{x}$:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^{+}} \frac {{x^{1.7}+1.7x^{0.7}}} {-0.7}$$
This is now trivially 0.

Answer (score 1):

We have that as $x \to 0^+$,

$$e^x-1 \sim x$$

$$\ln (e^x-1) \sim \ln x$$

Because,

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$$

So then our limit is the same as,

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{0.7} \ln x$$

$$=\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\ln x}{x^{-0.7}}$$

Proceed by l'Hopitals to get.

$$=\lim_{x \to \infty} -\frac{1}{0.7}x^{0.7}$$

$$=0$$